# How to perform this modification in the quicksort algorithm?

Tags: quicksort

I have implemented the quicksort algorithm like this:

```
static void quicksort(int elements[], int start, int end){
        if (start<end){
            int index=partition(elements,start,end);
            quicksort(elements,start,index-1);
            quicksort(elements,index+1,end);
        }
    }
    static void swap(int elements[],int i, int j){
        int temp=elements[i];
        elements[i]=elements[j];
        elements[j]=temp;
    }
    static int partition(int elements[],int start, int end){
        int index;
        int pivot=elements[end];
        int minIndex=start-1;
        for (int i=start;i<end;i++){
            if (elements[i]<pivot){
                minIndex++;
                swap(elements,minIndex,i);
            }
        }
       
        index=minIndex+1;
        swap(elements,index,end);
        return index;
```

The problem is that I want to modify, I believe that is the partition part, so that if I have an array to be ordered like this: [4,0,7,0,5,0,1] it prints [1,4,5,7,0,0,0]. I was thinking that one solution would be to traverse the array sequentially and create two subarrays, one that it has numbers different than 0s and the other filled up with 0s. After that I can apply quicksort to the first array and append it to the second. Is there any way to do it by modifying the partition function only?

Answer (score 1):

In my code below, it iterates from the partition index ( index ) to the end of the array. If it encounters a zero, it increments the zeroIndex and swap it with the current element. This effectively moves all the zeros to the end of the array.

Thus, 0s in the array are placed at the end after the partitioning step.

```
static int partition(int elements[], int start, int end) { 
    int index;
    int pivot = elements[end]; 
    int minIndex=start-1; 
    for (int i=start;i<end;i++) { 
        if (elements[i] <= pivot) { 
            minIndex++;
            swap(elements,minIndex,i); 
        } 
    } 

    index=minIndex+1;
    swap(elements,index,end); 
     
    int i, zeroIndex=index; 
    for (i=index;i<=end;i++) { 
        if (elements[i] == 0) { 
            zeroIndex++; 
            swap(elements,zeroIndex,i); 
        } 
    } 
    return zeroIndex;
}
```